# When would I use Kotlin annotations over interfaces?

Tags: java, kotlin, interface, annotations

Put differently, what is the difference between Kotlin interfaces and annotations?

I ask this because in the "Docs" I read that annotation classes are a form of interface, and to me, I cannot tell the main difference between the two. The link to the docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#instantiation

I have avoided asking this question but surprisingly, I could not find   a clear answer to this question online.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a link to the doc that reads that annotations are a form of interface?

Comment: In terms of _technical implementation_, an annotation is a specific kind of interface, but annotation objects are _attached to_ (annotate) other program elements to provide metadata.

Comment: @Joffrey, I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-, if I wanted to have a class implement a base interface that has no additional functions or attributes, would that be a good time to use an annotation instead?

Comment: @user18798042 , I would advice creating a playground program where you create hierarchies of classes or incorporating abstraction to it to have a grasp of the value of `Interfaces`, NEXT, look at some frameworks that uses annotations, I don't know which stack this question refers to, but if its Android, look at `Retrofit` but if this is backend stack maybe `Spring` or `Hibernate`?, regardless, pay attention how certain components (class or functions) are being "generated" automatically, be intrigued with how does Retrofit or Spring/Hibernate make those annotated components work like magic.

Comment: @user18798042, the kind of interface you mention is called a _marker interface_. Some of the uses for marker interfaces have been replaced by annotations since annotations were added in Java 5, but not all of them. It depends on specifics (and often on the convenience feature available by the tools you're using, such as Spring).

Comment: Okay, I think I understand better now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6):

No point about explaining what interfaces are here because there are thousands of articles about them because they are a basic feature in almost every OOP.

Annotations are technically a subtype of interfaces, but that’s not really helpful to understanding them because you don’t use them in typical code for purposes anything like interfaces.

Annotations are for attaching meta data to code, which can be used to enable features not directly supported by the language syntax.

In Kotlin, a number of them are provided for enabling JVM features that aren’t relevant to other platforms so they weren’t included in the language syntax. For example, `@Synchronized` and `@JvmField`. There’s also one for future-proofing inline classes on the JVM, `@JvmInline`, which is there to distinguish the compiled Kotlin-specific version of inline classes from the future default implementation that will be equivalent to Java `record`s.

On Android some are provided to enable compiler warnings and errors for issues specific to Android code, such as using the wrong type of resource ID as a function argument, e.g. `@ColorRes` or `@StringRes`. They also provide ones that can be used by the build tools after compilation, such as `@Keep`, which prevents a class from being minified and obfuscated in a release build.

Some libraries that use reflection provide annotations that help the library know what to do with code. For example, Gson, which is used for automatically converting classes to and from JSON Strings, has ones for specifying what name a field should be converted to in the String, for example.

Making your own is a somewhat advanced skill. It would be more common to do something like the ones used by GSON, if you building your own tool that uses reflection. But you could also use it for compiler tools and linters like the above Android examples.